# Solve this equation. Can anybody do it?

Tags: problem-solving

> $$x / y = a + b \log(y)$$

Above is a relation between `x` and `y`.
I have `x`. How do I find `y` ? Given: `a` and `b` are constants.

`a` is `0.710` while `b` is `-0.014`

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than through numerical methods.

Comment: If you do not have access to Lambert function, only numerical methods would work. If you want, post values for $a$ and $b$ and I shall show you.

Comment: given a and b above. added now. @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given value of $x$, you want to solve for $y$ $$x / y = a + b ~ \log(y)$$ $a$ and $b$ being given constants. So, for example, let us write the equation as $$f(y)=y \Big( a + b ~ \log(y) \Big)-x$$ and you search $y$ such that $f(y)=0$.

A simple method for this kind of problem is Newton  scheme which, starting from a guess $y_0$ will generate iterates according to $$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac {f(y_n)}{f'(y_n)}$$ So, let us be very lazy and start iterating at $y_0=1$ using your values for $a$ and $b$ and $x=10$. The succesive iterates will then be $14.3477$, $14.8763$, $14.8765$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could know how we can solve by Lambert W function. Even you presented a different equation than the first answer by @RobertIsrael. So how does that work?

Comment: There are two real solutions in this case: the other is 
approximately $1.05909 \times 10^{22}$.

Comment: To use the Lambert W function, you need software (generally a computer algebra system such as Maple or Mathematica or Sage) that has it.  Or you can use Wolfram Alpha online.

Comment: What if I become lazier still and start iterating at $y_0 = 0$ instead of $1$ as shown, or with some other value? I mean what is it that decides which value to iterate with initially? More clarification please. @RobertIsrael and ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: $y_0 = 0$ won't work because $f$ has a singularity there ($\lim_{y \to 0+} f(y) = 0$ but $\lim_{y \to 0+} f'(y)$ is infinite).  Other starting points are ok, as long as you don't run into negative values of $y$.

Comment: Ok, sir. I am getting to learn so much here. Another small doubt. It is not necessary that my starting guess has to be less than my possible answer, is it? It can be greater too, right? @RobertIsrael

Comment: Correct.  As long as the starting guess is sufficiently close to a solution, it will converge to that solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires the Lambert W function.

$$ y = \exp\left(W(x e^{a/b}/b) - a/b\right)$$

Comment: any extra info? like a demo or example. I mean how should I proceed?

Comment: @Robert Israel. Wouldn't it be simpler as $$y=\frac{x}{b W\left(\frac{x e^{a/b}}{b}\right)}$$

Comment: So which one is correct? Any solution by this Lambert's method?

Comment: Both are correct.  If $u = W(v)$, then $u e^u = v$.
Also note that there are two real-valued branches of $W(v)$ on the interval $(-1/e, 0)$.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much. I will have to try this in Wolfram Alpha. It's just that I have no idea about this function and how to try at WA. Anyway, I will try. Thank you again.

Comment: You can simply ask WA: solve 10/y=0.710 - 0.014 log(y).
Note that WA calls Lambert W "product log".